# Laravel ui authentification by bootstrap

Tags: laravel-authentication

composer require `laravel/ui`

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

npm install && npm run dev
```

I run those commands but when I go run my app in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`

It gives me below error:

> error:Vite manifest not found at:
> C:\Users\lenovo\laravel-projects\ProjetFE\public\build/manifest.json

[image]

I tried to create authentification for my laravel app using laravel ui with bootstrap.